# Sending email from web site using Google Apps account

Tags: c#, gmail

Been researching this issue for quite a while, but have yet to find any solution.

I can send email from the website using my regular gmail account using smtp.gmail.com as my host and port 587.

My current problem is that there's no problem sending the mail.  I no longer receive an error.  However, the email is never sent.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the code:

**Config:**

```
<smtp from="admin@domain.com">
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="password" userName="admin@domain.com" port="587"/>
</smtp>
```

**Code:**

```
    public void Send() {

        bool bDev = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dev"] == "true";

        MailMessage oMsg = new MailMessage();

        foreach (string sAddress in To) {
                if (sAddress != "") oMsg.To.Add(sAddress);
        }

        oMsg.From = ((FromName == null) || (FromName == "")) ?
                    new MailAddress(From) :
                    new MailAddress(From, FromName);
        oMsg.Subject = Subject;

        oMsg.Body = Body.ToString();
        oMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        oMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.EnableSsl = (new int[] { 587, 465 }).Contains(smtp.Port);
        smtp.Send(oMsg);
    }
```

Comment: Are From, FromName and Subject public fields/properties in your class? I have had very similar issues. Instead of using your web.config file to specify your network settings, rewrite it in C# code (within your Send method) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes they are.  Just hardcoded them and retested. Same problem.

Comment: Please keep your code as is but use a different SMTP client to test (get a new account POP/SMTP account (Yahoo, GMX), to rule out if the issue is your code, GMAIL, other!

Comment: also before you try to refactor your code check to see if there is a `Priority` property in regards to how you are sending the code and when you want it to be set.. `set it to `Hight` for example to see it it gets pushed quicker. `Hard coding is not a good practice btw`

Comment: Tested with a non Gmail smtp server, and it sent it just fine.  Made a change in my code to add a second email address (my personal gmail account), and it was received successfully to both addresses.  Then I removed the personal gmail account and retested and it started working fine.  Very odd.

Comment: However, the reply to address is using my admin@domain.com account instead of the email address I'm assigning to email.From.  Is this something that I can override?

Comment: Added a new property for ReplyTo. oMsg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(ReplyToAddress).  The header for my email shows the correct information, but when I click reply, the email uses my admin@domain.com account info for the reply to address, ignoring my reply-to address.

from:  Company Name <admin@domain.com>
reply-to:  bob@bob.com
to:  admin@domain.com
date:  Mon, Mar 25, 2013 at 10:08 AM
subject:  Contact Us
mailed-by:  domain.com

Is Gmail ignoring the reply-to for fraud prevention possibly?

Answer (score 1):

I added a second To address and resumed testing.  I began to receive email to both accounts.  Then after removing the second address, it started working.

I ran into a new issue where my reply-to address was using the From address.  So, I added additional code to set the reply address to that of the person's email address from my form.

Code

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReplyToAddress))
        oMsg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(ReplyToAddress);
```

However, I ran into an issue with Gmail ignoring my defined reply-to address, and using my from address.  Apparently this is by design.  I couldn't find any useful information on how to override this setting, so instead I did a workaround that might prove to be helpful to anyone else having this issue.

I created a generic email address with gmail (website@gmail.com) and setup a filter.  Any emails coming from admin@domain.com need to be redirected to admin@domain.com.

Now, when I run my tests, all the emails are going where they are supposed to go AND the reply to field works great.

Not the best solution as it involves me remembering to setup a new account every time I run into this issue, but it's a solution that works for the time being until a better alternative comes up.

Comment: I can also create another email address off the domain account and then forward it from there.  That's a little nicer if you have that option.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly same issue, that no error happened but also no email was sent.  Google sometimes blocks your account(usually during testing).  Try logging in into gmail account and see what it says.

UPD1: also check your sent folder in gmail.

UPD2:  Also make sure that "From" email is the same as your gmail email address.